# Split text file into lines, Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, strip

I want to split a text file in python, using the following peice of code:

```
inputfile = open(sys.argv[1]).read()   
for line in inputfile.strip().split("\n"):
    print line
```

the problem is, that it's read the first 12 lines only!! the file is large more than 10 thousand lines!

What is the possible reason!

Thanks,

Comment: You should uses `open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()` which returns list of lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating on a file using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255273/iterating-on-a-file-using-python)

Comment: be *lazy* `with open(sys.argv[1]) as f: for line in f: print(line)` add indention of course

Comment: @Arount even better, iterate over the file-handler directly, which iterates over lines lazily.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right :) @OP: `for line in open(sys.argv[1]):`

Comment: is there two files i .e `inputfile` and `linksfile`?

Comment: @mahendra kamble nice !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        print(line)
```

Use readlines() which will generate list automatically and no need to read by "\n".

Comment: @noor, are you getting any error ? Does prompt stuck up or end execution normally ?

Comment: No I commented  everything in the file until this part run correctly

Comment: @noor, I want to know the behavior of code after reading 15 lines !

Comment: Nothing else, I tried to put this code in a separated python file (i.e the only piece of code you wrote)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141527/discussion-between-raj-damani-and-noor).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
text = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Test\Text.txt"

oFile = open(text, 'r')
line = oFile.readline()[:-1]
while line:
    splitLine = line.split(' ')
    print splitLine
    line = oFile.readline()[:-1]
oFile.close()
```

I use this style to iterate through huge text files at work