# How to split texts into sentences and write them to xml

Tags: python, xml, text

I am trying to structure my text document in an xml structure, where each sentence gets an id. I have text documents with unstructured sentences and I would like to split the sentences using a '.' delimiter and write them to xml. Here is my code:

```
    import re

    #Read the file
    with open ('C:\\Users\\ngwak\\Documents\\test.txt') as f:
        content = [f]
        split_content = []
        for element in content:
            split_content += re.split("(.)\s+", element)

        print(split_content, sep='\n\n')
```

But I am getting this error already and I cant interpret it:

```
    TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

How can I split my sentences and write them to xml? Thanks a lot.
This is how my txt file looks like:

> In a formal sense, the germ of national consciousness can be traced back to the Peace Treaty of Hoachanas signed in 13–June-1858 between soldiers, all the  chiefs except those of the Bondelswarts (who had not been involved in the previous fighting), as well as by Muewuta, two sons of  amuaha, formerly a Commandant of Chief Onag of the Triku people. There is ample epistolary as well as oral evidence for this view. The most poignant statement is to be found in the now famous and oft-quoted letter of Onag to Bonagha written on May 13, 1890 in which, amongst other things, he says that on June 13 there are people coming. Again on the 01.02.2015 till the 01.05 there are some coming.

And I would like the sentences to be like this in xml:

```
    <sentence id=01>In a formal sense, the germ of national consciousness 
    can be traced back to the Peace Treaty of Hoachanas signed in 13–June-
    1858 between soldiers, all the  chiefs except those of the Bondelswarts 
    (who had not been involved in the previous fighting), as well as by 
    Muewuta, two sons of  amuaha, formerly a Commandant of Chief Onag of the 
    Triku people. </sentence>
```

Comment: What line are you getting that error?

Comment: There is only one element in `content` and it's a file object. I'm not sure why you're doing `content = [f]`

Comment: You need `content = f.readlines()`

Comment: @Summer Evans on the line split_content += re.split("(.)\s+", element). I got that, I was trying to parse the content over... Anyways, I change it but it not printing anything for me to see how it split the sentences.

Comment: Does your text file have any newlines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
text_file = open('C:\\Users\\ngwak\\Documents\\test.txt', "r")
textLinesFromFile = text_file.read().replace("\n","").split('.')

for sentenceNumber in range (0,len(textLinesFromFile)):
    print (textLinesFromFile[sentenceNumber].strip())
    #Or write each sentence in your XML
```

Comment: Does exactly what I need for splitting the sentences. Thank you. Do you know how I can write each sentence to xml?. I will try too.

Comment: @NampaGwakondo, search for Python XML libraries. (Also, this should be the accepted answer.)

Comment: @SumnerEvans could you please have a look at my update. I am trying to save the results to a new textfile but I have an error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `content = [f]` line.

```
with open ('C:\\Users\\ngwak\\Documents\\test.txt') as file:
    split_content = []
    for element in file:
        split_content += re.split("(.)\s+", element)

    print(split_content, sep='\n\n')
```

File objects are iterable. Using them in a `for` loop will iterate over each line.

---

**Further Reading**

- [Methods on File objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) in the Python Docs
- The example in this SO answer: [Iterating on a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255273/iterating-on-a-file-using-python#10255293)

Comment: @Summer Evans thanks for your correction. I noticed I didnt need the content = [f] but when I changed it I still cannot print to see the split sentences.

Comment: @NampaGwakondo, please update your question and add a bit more description on what you are seeing currently and what you want to see.

Comment: I am actually not seeing anything. I have edited my question as to what I want to have at the end of the day.