# Why "for line in file:" can only use once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple question which I stock in it !

`for line1 in file:
    print(line1)
for line2 in file:
    print(line2)
for line3 in file:
    print(line3)`

I expect this to work three times, but only "for line1 in file:" work.

Comment: For a simple fix, add `file.seek(0)` in between every `for` loop.

Comment: @Tomothy32: Unless `file` is backed by a transient thing (pipe, socket, etc.). In which case you only get one shot at it, and must either slurp to memory (e.g. as a `list`) if you trust you'll have enough memory, or copy to a temp file which you then reread with `seek`s.

Comment: Better duplicate: [Iterating on a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255273/iterating-on-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the file is read as part of iterating over the lines. You'll need to reopen the file each time, or read the whole file into a list of lines (via file.readlines() perhaps) and iterate over that, if memory limits permit. 
Any open file has a "read pointer" that tracks what's been read, which advances with each line consumed. The loops as written will each consume the whole file.

Comment: "You'll need to reopen the file each time, or read the whole file into a list of lines (via file.readlines() perhaps) and iterate over that" - or, as @Tomothy32 says, "be kind, rewind".