# How can I iterate over a file more than once?

Tags: python, file

Currently, this code is giving me all lines from `searchfile` once. But with my newbie understanding, it should print out all lines from `searchfile` for every `infile` line!

```
searchfile = open('.\sometext.txt', 'r')
infile = open('.\somefile', 'r')

for line1 in infile:
    for line2 in searchfile:
        print line2

searchfile.close()
infile.close()
```

I tried to use `searchfile.readlines()` to create a list to print all `infile` lines for all `searchfile` lines, but it still does not work. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Duplicate: [Iterating on a file doesn't work the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10255273/7851470)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `searchfile` current position to the beginning for every `infile` iteration. you can use `seek` function for this.

```
searchfile = open('.\sometext.txt', 'r')
infile = open('.\somefile', 'r')

for line1 in infile:
    searchfile.seek(0,0)
    for line2 in searchfile:
        print line2

searchfile.close()
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

I suppose `searchfile` is a file you opened earlier, e. g. `searchfile = open('.\someotherfile', 'r')`.

In this case, your construction doesn't work, because a file is an iterable which can be iterated over only once and then it is exhausted.

You have two options here:

1. Reopen the file on every outer loop fun
2. Read the file's contents into a list an iterate over this list as often as you need to.

---

What happens in your code?

At the start of the nested `for` loops, both your files are open and can be read from.

Whenever the first inner loop run is over, `searchfile` is at its end. When the outer loop now comes to process its second entry, the inner loop is like an empty loop, as it just cannot produce more entries.

Comment: I used the seek function for the inner loop. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 5):

## The `in` and `with` keywords

You don't need two nested for loops!
Instead use the more pythonic `in` keyword like so:

```
with open("./search_file.txt", mode="r") as search_file:
    lines_to_search = search_file.readlines()

with open("./file_to_search.txt", mode="r") as file_to_search:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file_to_search, start=1):
        if line in lines_to_search:
            print(f"Match at line {line_number}: {line}")
```

**Pro tip:** Open your files using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to automatically close them.

Comment: Thanks for the pro tip! I used the seek function and it solves the problem. You are creating a list and only one for loop, which seems to be more efficient! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

We need a bit more details about what are your objects in this code. But you probably would like to do:

```
    infile = open('.\somefile', 'r')

    for line1 in infile:
       for line2 in line1:
         print line2

    searchfile.close()
    infile.close()
```

If your infile is a list of lists - That are the cases where a nested for loop would make sense.

Comment: @Kevin Winnik stated, that two files exist. And that a line of `searchfile` is supposed to be printed for every line of `infile`.