# Confusion about the scope and visibility of variable and argument in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scope, local-variables

I don't understand why do the test1 and test2 will return 2 different output when they are the same.

```
   python3.7.4

   fin=open('D:\Python\Think Python\words.txt')

   def build_list_append(file):
       word_list=[]
       for line in fin:
           word=line.strip()
           word_list.append(word)
       return word_list

   def test1(worklist1=build_list_append(fin)):
       print("This is test1,It will return a non-empty list")
       print(len(worklist1))

   def test2(worklist2=build_list_append(fin)):
       print("This is test2,It will return an empty list")
       print(len(worklist2))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating on a file doesn't work the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255273/iterating-on-a-file-doesnt-work-the-second-time)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 is right. You can safe the contents of your file to a variable and everything should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Short Answer**: That's because once `test1()` is called, read pointer will move to end of file. Once `test2()` is called there are no lines left to read, hence `0` length.

**Long Answer:**

At `fin = open('D:\Python\Think Python\words.txt')` the read pointer will point at the beginning of the file.

Once `file1()` is called, it will call `build_list_append(fin)` which will iterate through the file line-by-line. Because of this all lines will be store in `word_list` and length will be returned.

Now, the pointer is pointing at the end of the file.

After calling `test2()`, program again calls `build_list_append(fin)` which **want** to iterate through whole file line-by-line, **but since pointer is already at end of the file it doesn't have any content to go through**. Hence, length 0 is returned.

If you try closing the file and pass a fresh file object, `test2()` will return same value as `test1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program again, except with the `fin = open(...)` statement *inside* the function `build_list_append()` (make sure to add a `fin.close()` at the end as well). Then, they'll act the same.

File objects in python (those returned by `open()`) belong to a class of object called a *generator**. Generators are iterable, and lazily return element after element as necessary. What differentiates them from, say, lists, is that you can't go *backwards* in a generator - you can only ever get the next element. So when you run out of elements, you get nothing.

That's what's happening here. The loop `for line in fin` exhausts all the elements that the file object can produce, the first time it's executed. When you execute it again, the generator has no more to give, and so the `for` loop doesn't run, and you get an empty list. Unless you re-create the generator from the start, by calling `open()` again, it has run out of elements.

---

*it's more complicated than this, and technically file objects aren't generators, but they act sufficiently similar to draw the comparison.