# Why is my for-loop over a file not starting after using readlines()?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read info from a file and print it's information. Using a test program, I could get it working like this:

```py
file = open("cooltextfile.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    if "BobRoss" in line:
        print(line)
```

Using above method, it prints all lines containing "Bob Ross".

However, when I use it in my main program like this, it's not even printing the line if I tell it to print the whole line:

```py
number = 0
index = 0

textFile = open("cooltextfile.txt", "r")
lineInfo = textFile.readlines()

for line in textFile:
    index += 1

    print(line) # - An attempt to print the entire line
                    
    if "BobRoss" in line:
        number += 1

        print(str(number) + ". " + line)
        print("Order: " + lineInfo[index])
                
textFile.close()
```

Upon further inspection it would seem that the for-loop never starts. Any reason as to what could be causing the loop to not start?

Comment: Use `with open() as :` instead of `= open()`, it's cleaner.

Comment: You exhaust the file with 'textFile.readlines()'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating on a file doesn't work the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255273/iterating-on-a-file-doesnt-work-the-second-time)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

1. use `enumerate` to get the index,
2. you have to loop through the lines, so use `lines = file.readlines()` or it will get just a character
3. use fstrings instead of [`concatenation`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-concatenation/), it will be faster
4. use `with open(filename,'r')`, instead of `fp = open(filename)`it will be cleaner and it will close your file at the end automatically.

code reassembled:

```
with open("cooltextfile.txt",'r') as textFile:
    number,index = 0,0
    lines=textFile.readlines()
    for index,line in enumerate(lines): 
        if "BobRoss" in line:
            number += 1 #incrementing the number of lines that contains BobRoss
            print(f"{number}.{line}") 
            print(f"Order: {index}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of reading a file like playing a tape.
You called `textFile.readlines()`, now you've reached the end of the tape.
Now you try to play it again (in a loop), but you're still at the end of the tape.
You need to rewind the tape before: `textFile.seek(0)`