# Python nested loop using csv and list file

Tags: python, csv

I'm using the following code to search for a list of IDs in a particular column of a csv file

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

with open(r"C:\Test\inputTest.csv", newline = '') as inputFile:
   inputReader   = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=",")
   idFile = open(r"C:\Test\testids.txt")
   loopcounter = 1
   for inputRow in inputReader:
    loopcountr+= 1
    print (loopcounter)
    inputString = inputRow[18]
    for id in idFile:
        print ("id: ", id)
        print ("InputString", inputString)
        result = inputString.find(id)
        print (result)
```

But the nested loop with the id file runs only once, and then doesn't run again.

Output:

```
1
 id:  123388

InputString  ID
-1
 id:  112233

InputString  ID
-1
 id:  141414
InputString  ID
-1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Any idea why the 2nd loop (the nested loop) doesn't run every time?

Comment: Can you print idFile? What does that look like?

Everything looks okay (except loopcountr+=1 should be loopcounter+=1), so I'm assuming that there's something going on with the idFile array you're trying to iterate through.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `with` to open `idFile`? You obviously know about it, since you use it for `inputFile`.

Comment: Because after the first row, `idFile` is positioned at end of file.  You've read the entire thing, and there is nothing left to read.  You should read `idFile` into a list, and then iterate over the list.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255273/iterating-on-a-file-doesnt-work-the-second-time

Comment: Move `idFile = open(r"C:\Test\testids.txt")` after `for inputRow in inputReader:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I call read() twice on an open file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906137/why-cant-i-call-read-twice-on-an-open-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Tim Roberts mentioned in the comment, "You should read idFile into a list, and then iterate over the list."

You can read the test IDs into a list, like this:

```py
with open("test_ids.txt") as f:
    test_ids = []
    for line in f:
        test_ids.append(line.strip())
```

Or, if you're comfortable with list comprehensions in Python, this is equivalent:

```py
with open("test_ids.txt") as f:
    test_ids = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]
```

Then, when you're reading the CSV file (presumably) you can compare some data from the CSV against the test IDs.

That could look something like the following.  I'm also using `enumerate()` to count the iterations for me:

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # discard header

    for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        input_id = row[0]  # don't use 'id', it's a reserved word
        name = row[1]
        print(f"row #:{i}, input_ID:{input_id}, Name:{name}")

        for test_id in test_ids:
            if test_id == input_id:
                print(f"  {name} matches test_ID {test_id}")
```

I mocked up this data.  The CSV has the ID in the first column, `row[0]` from the code above:

```
test_ids.txt
============
105
108

input.csv
=========
ID,Name
105,Alice
106,Bing
107,Che
108,Dee
```

When I run that code I get:

```
row #:1, input_ID:105, Name:Alice
  Alice matches test_ID 105
row #:2, input_ID:106, Name:Bing
row #:3, input_ID:107, Name:Che
row #:4, input_ID:108, Name:Dee
  Dee matches test_ID 108
```

And that's how you can implement a nested loop.

If you're comfortable with doing "lookups" in dictionaries, you can get rid of the nested loop:

```py
with open("test_ids.txt") as f:
    test_ids = {}
    for line in f:
        test_ids[line.strip()] = None
```

The test_ids dictionary looks like:

```py
{'105': None, '108': None}
```

And now you simply check if each input ID is "in" that dictionary:

```py
with open("input.csv", newline="") as f:
    ... 
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
        ...
        if input_id in test_ids:
            print(f"  {name} found in test_IDs")
```

That produces the similar output:

```
row #:1, input_ID:105, Name:Alice
  Alice found in test_IDs
row #:2, input_ID:106, Name:Bing
row #:3, input_ID:107, Name:Che
row #:4, input_ID:108, Name:Dee
  Dee found in test_IDs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for so much detail. I used list iteration to solve my problem, but I'll definitely look to improve my code using other suggestions you've given